# Android SupportMapFragment Dimmed When in Faked Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, google-maps-android-api-2

So I have a Map in a Dialog-Styled Activity, however when i set the Dim Background it also dims the Map. This is only being seen on Galaxy Tab 10 2 (4.0.1) but we have limited devices.

Set Dim background code//

```
    activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
.....
params.dimAmount = 0.5f;
        activity.getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
```

Output

[image]

Does anyone have a workaround for this type of issue? For now we will have to remove the background dimming but this is not a great option.

TA!

Comment: Get rid of the dimming code, it dims everything behind the dialog. What you could do is place layout with transparent black background and draw the portion of the map with pure Color.TRANSPARENT with your canvas.

Comment: true but the actionbar would be shown across the top of the screen with this method correct? I guess i could create a a fake action bar myself.

Comment: No need to implement your own actionbar. You can also avoid drawing the dimmed background to the width and height of the actionbar. :)

Comment: So I can dim around the dialog but not behind it? Could you point me in the direction of how to do this?